# Converting Channels into strings in Nextflow DSL2

Tags: groovy, bioinformatics, nextflow

I'm wondering how to extract the content of a Nextflow Channel and make it a string, within the workflow block.

I'd need this for example to:

- define a switch system using Groovy maps, where the map key is selected based on a process' output
- using the watchPath method to watch a path which is the output of a previous process
- any other kind of situation where a string is needed but the value of the string is dynamic and not fixed

I already tried .toString(), .map{}, .view() and everything I could find in the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering how to extract the content of a Nextflow Channel and
> make it a string

Best to avoid trying to do this. If you just want to select a map key based on a process' output, you can simply declare your map in your workflow block and use it as required. For example:

```
process test {

    input:
    val myval

    output:
    path "${myval}.txt"

    """
    touch "${myval}.txt"
    """
}

workflow {

    def foobarbaz = ['foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'baz': 3]

    Channel.of('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
        | test
        | map { tuple( foobarbaz[ it.baseName ], it ) }
        | view()
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.10.0
Launching `main.nf` [high_faggin] DSL2 - revision: 43aaa56eee
executor >  local (3)
[0e/0fd6dc] process > test (3) [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
[1, /path/to/work/a7/d501cb2a8426c5639117d14e8fb7fe/foo.txt]
[2, /path/to/work/22/df9cc4f1d34b9cca0d0331fac5c150/bar.txt]
[3, /path/to/work/0e/0fd6dc0519a34c52903b990755f450/baz.txt]
```

Note that you do not need the [watchPath](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#watchpath) factory method to watch the output path of a previous process. Simply define the previous process' outputs in the [output](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#outputs) block and declare them as [inputs](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#inputs) in the downstream process' [input](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#inputs) block. For example:

```
process foo {

    input:
    val myval

    output:
    path "${myval}.txt"

    """
    echo "value: ${myval}" > "${myval}.txt"
    """
}

process bar {

    input:
    path myfile

    output:
    stdout

    """
    echo "Contents of ${myfile}:" 
    cat "${myfile}"
    """
}

workflow {

    Channel.of('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
        | foo 
        | bar
        | view()
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.10.0
Launching `main.nf` [clever_lovelace] DSL2 - revision: c388bd26af
executor >  local (6)
[ac/1be228] process > foo (2) [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
[11/7b3c6e] process > bar (1) [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
Contents of foo.txt:
value: foo

Contents of bar.txt:
value: bar

Contents of baz.txt:
value: baz
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful. Just one thing about the watchPath: I was thinking of getting the path to watch from a previous process since it is variable and not fixed, but it seems watchPath() only accepts strings as an argument.

Comment: @LucaForlani Correct - `watchPath()` is a channel factory method so it's not a good fit for that. Usually it's just used to watch a directory that another (external) process would write files to at some point. And usually you tend to know what that directory is ahead of time. So I suspect you have a design problem but I don't know enough of the details to offer any guidance at this point. If you feel like outlining the problem with some specifics (by [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) another question), I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: Don't worry, I figured it out too: if it seems you can't do something in nextflow, probably you were supposed to do it in a different way. Thanks for your help, it was precious :)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into getting the value from a channel and was getting `DataFlowVariable(null)` when trying to print out the stdout channel although when I used `view` I could see the value.  I then looked at the api doc for [DataFlowVariable](http://www.gpars.org/webapp/api/javadoc/groovyx/gpars/dataflow/DataflowVariable.html) and realized that the `then` function can wait for the value to be set in the asynchronous channel.

I didn't see this mentioned in the Nextflow docs so this is probably not a best practice but could be useful in certain situations.

```
process output_json {
    output:
    stdout

    script:
    """
    echo '{"a": true}'
    """
}

workflow {
    json = output_json | collect
    json.then { print json.val[0] }
}
```